# TV show about man transforming into animals

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I recall very rough memories about a TV show where a man could transform into animals, which you might help me identify. I watched it a long time ago and it should be a US-show from the 80s or very early 90s.

I don't remember why he did that or why he could do it, I only remember him being able to morph into certain animals, a puma and a hawk, I think. I have a feeling he was some kind of doctor, maybe a psychiatrist. And regarding his looks I remember him looking similar to the faceman from the A-team, at least his haircut (well, who didn't have such a haircut at that time?).

Comment: If you google "TV show about man transforming into animals" you get [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manimal) as the first result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Manimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manimal) :)

The Wiki page says

> While Jonathan had the ability to change himself into any animal, he
>   would transform into a hawk and a black panther in nearly every
>   episode.

Comment: Yep - starring the recently deceased Simon McCorkindale. Rick Baker did the fx, although the budget only allowed for a couple of transformations. Fun times!

Comment: I actually just heard about this from NPR's 'Wait Wait Don't Tell Me' the other day. It looks even more ridiculous than they originally made it sound.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's from the movie *The Island of Dr. Moreau*, wherein he transforms 2 animals by crossbreeding them I think. Sort of an experiment.

Answer (score -2):

*[Visionaries - Knights of the Magical Light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visionaries:_Knights_of_the_Magical_Light)* was an animated TV series where humans would transform into animals like lion etc.

[IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092476/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) description :

> The planet Prysmos - post-technological loss. Two groups rise to dominance from the devastation to wage war upon each other. One is controlled by honest and law-abiding people and the other by criminals and villains. Following an open challenge thrown down by the great wizard Merklynn, fourteen surviving knights are granted powers of transformation and magical energy. The groups are now divided between the good Spectral Knights and the evil Darkling Lords. The battle for supremacy begins...